# Sorting SQL string by first 2 or 3 characters

Tags: sql, sql-server, sorting

I have been asked to sort a locations table in ascending order. The data in the table currently looks something like this:

- 100F01
- 105B02
- 10B01
- GK1-A01
- 201E12
- 20A01

However, when this data is displayed on the screen I want it to sort the numeric results in ascending order and then the string results in alphabetic order. The output should look something like this:

- 10B01
- 20A01
- 100F01
- 105B02
- 201E12
- GK1-A01

I have tried using the following code

```
SELECT location FROM freelocations
ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTRING(location, 1, 2) AS INT)
```

however, as expected, this returns an error message because some locations don't start with a numeric:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'GK' to data type int.

Any ideas or tips will be greatly appreciated

Comment: I forgot to mention I am running this query on a Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Comment: Are you sure you want to order the numeric part in ascending order?, then why is `100F01` before than `20A01`?, should'nt the `20` be before the `100`?. Can't you just do `ORDER BY location`?

Comment: @Lamak that was my mistake as I was typing it in. You are correct. It should go 10's then 20's...100's etc etc

Comment: @Lamak if I order by location the issue still persists

Comment: Then try `ORDER BY LEN(location), location`

Comment: @Lamak If I use your command the result I get is: 
- 194A
- 194B
- 260A
- 10B02                         
- 12F01      
which is still incorrect.

Comment: @Strawberry could you please explain what exactly that command is doing

Comment: does SQL Server have regex replacing functions?

Comment: It's trying to interpret everything as a number. Those it cannot interpret will be treated as 0. However, things like 201e12 will be misinterpreted as very large numbers!

Comment: How do you want to handle the SECOND numeric part (as in '201E12')?  Is it to be treated as string data ?

Comment: @hugh all the results are treated as String

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
select location 
from freelocations
order by 
    case 
       when patindex('%[^0-9]%', location) = 1 then 9999999999
       else cast(substring(location, 1, patindex('%[^0-9]%', location) - 1) as int)
    end,
    location
```

(It's a bit clumsy due to SQL Server lacking a regex replace function)

Comment: by the way, is there a way to use regex in SQL Server? not that I am planning on using it, just curious :)

Comment: @OopsieDaisie: not really. The patindex function and LIKE operator accept something like a regular expression, but it's far from the level of completeness offered e.g. by PostgreSQL or Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

Before casting you should check if the first 2 or 3 characters really are digits:

```
SELECT
  location
FROM
  freelocations
ORDER BY
  CASE
    WHEN location like '[0-9][0-9][0-9]%' THEN cast(substring(location,1,3) AS INT)
    WHEN location like '[0-9][0-9]%' THEN cast(substring(location,1,2) AS INT)
    ELSE 9999
  END
```

Comment: I am getting a syntax error. Is this a T-SQL syntax or MySQL?

Comment: T-SQL. You would have to replace @tbl with your table.

Answer (score 0):

order by FIELD(string+0,1),string+0

but note that '10e20' will be misinterpreted!

Answer (score 0):

Try this to avoid casting:

```
SELECT 
    x,
    RIGHT('000' +LEFT (x,patindex('%[^0-9]%',x)-1),3) sort1,
    RIGHT (x,LEN(x)-patindex('%[^0-9]%',x)+1) sort2
FROM
(
    SELECT '123asdf' x
    UNION
    SELECT '12asdf'     
    UNION
    SELECT '13asdf'  
    UNION
    SELECT '12zsdf'  
) X
ORDER BY sort1 ,sort2
```